# Where do I file this ndk bug?

Tags: android, ndk-build

I have found a bug in the Android NDK compiler (r16b).  Code snippet is shown below:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdint.h>

int frameWidth = 208;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int32_t count = (argc > 1) ? atoi(argv[1]) : -1;
    int width = frameWidth;
    int rows = count / (width * sizeof(int16_t));
    if (rows >= 3) {
        printf("rows=%u\n", rows);
    } else {
        printf("count=%d rows=%d\n", count, rows);
    }
}
```

The problem is the gcc/llvm compiler is treating the divide as an unsigned divide.  You can see this by compiling the code to a cmdline executable and running with no arguments or a negative number and/or generating the assembly code and looking at the arm source:

```
@DEBUG_VALUE: main:count <- %R4
        .loc    1 11 22 is_stmt 0       @ ./main.c:11:22
        mov     r0, r4
.Ltmp8:
        bl      __aeabi_uidiv
        mov     r2, r0
.Ltmp9:
        @DEBUG_VALUE: main:rows <- %R2
        .loc    1 12 9 is_stmt 1        @ ./main.c:12:9
        cmp     r2, #3
        blt     .LBB0_5
```

Where do I report this bug so it can be fixed?  I can imagine there are other places in our code where a signed divide is expected.

Comment: Bugs can be exploited by hackers, are you sure you're not revealing anything related to security?

Answer (score 0):

You can report issues in the official NDK GitHub [repository](https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk):

https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues

Comment: Thanks, will do that soon